# Javascript: Created input field doesn't show

Tags: javascript, createelement

The following produces no visible input text field.  What gives?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var my_input = document.createElement('INPUT');
my_input.type="text; 
my_input.value = "blah";
document.body.appendChild(my_input);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your code

```
my_input.type="text;
```

should be

```
my_input.type="text";
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

Easy way

```
document.write("<input type=\"text\"...blah blah...></input>");
```

Or correct your error

```
my_input.type="text;
```

to

```
my_input.type="text";
```

Note: Change the  `...blah blah...`